# C++ sort multidimensional array

Tags: c++

I am new in C++
I have simple quesstion
my array:

```
reporter[3][2] = { {0, 7}, {1, 12}, {2, 3} };
```

I want to sort like this:

```
{ {1, 12}, {0, 7}, {2, 3} };
```

I want to sort by second sector.
thanks a lot

Comment: Have you looked at [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: What is the basis of this sort? I meant, why {1,12} is before {0,7}?

Comment: I want to sort my array by second numbers. 12, 7, 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done is some steps:

Take all 2nd elements to a 1D array of structures. Let it is `node temp[];`

where `node` is like this:

```
struct node{
    int value;
    int position;
};
```

Sort them using any technique on basis of `temp[i].value`.

Then copy the array to a resultant array according to the `temp[i].position` from the sorted array.

Comment: Take time and try to code yourself. I just told you how you can do this.